# Synchronous API request to Asynchronous API request Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, swift2

Well I am new to Swift and I don't know much of completion handler. I want to get a request from an API and parse the JSON response so I can get the token. But what's happening with my code is that whenever I call the `getAuthentication` function my UI freezes and waiting for the data to get. Here is the code for `getAuthentication`

```
func getAuthentication(username: String, password: String){
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    let baseURL = "Some URL here"
    let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = "{\n  \"username\": \"\(username)\",\n  \"password\": \"\(password)\"\n}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
            print(swiftyJSON)

            //parse the data to get the user
            self.id = swiftyJSON["id"].intValue
            self.token = swiftyJSON["meta"]["token"].stringValue
        } else {
            print("There was an error")
        }
      dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }
    task.resume()
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

then, I am calling this method in my LoginViewController. Someone says that I am using a Synchronous request thats why my UI freezes, but I have really no idea on how to change it to Async and wait for the data to be downloaded. Can someone help me with this? Any help will much be appreciated.

Comment: Checkout [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). It's a handy framework to perform asynchronous HTTP requests.

Comment: Simply get rid of the semaphore; you are blocking the main thread with that. You need to process the response in the completion closure

Comment: @Reginald, `dataTaskWithRequest` function of `NSURLSession` used here is an asynchronous function. No need to use `dispatch_queue` here. You can check my answer. Feel free to comment for any doubts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, remove `dispatch_semaphore` related code from your function.

```
func getAuthentication(username: String, password: String){

   let baseURL = "Some URL here"
   let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)!
   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
   request.HTTPBody = "{\n  \"username\": \"\(username)\",\n  \"password\": \"\(password)\"\n}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

   let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
   let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

       if error == nil{
          let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
          print(swiftyJSON)

          //parse the data to get the user
          self.id = swiftyJSON["id"].intValue
          self.token = swiftyJSON["meta"]["token"].stringValue
       } else {
          print("There was an error")
       }
   }
   task.resume()
}
```

In the above code, the function `dataTaskWithRequest` itself is an asynchronus function. So, you don't need to call the function `getAuthentication` in a background thread.

For adding the completion handler,

```
func getAuthentication(username: String, password: String, completion:((sucess: Bool) -> Void)){

   let baseURL = "Some URL here"
   let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)!
   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
   request.HTTPBody = "{\n  \"username\": \"\(username)\",\n  \"password\": \"\(password)\"\n}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

   let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
   let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

       var successVal: Bool = true

       if error == nil{
          let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
          print(swiftyJSON)
          self.id = swiftyJSON["id"].intValue
          self.token = swiftyJSON["meta"]["token"].stringValue
       } else {
          print("There was an error")
          successVal = false
       }

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
          completion(successVal)                 
       })
   }
   task.resume()
}
```

It can be called as follows:

```
self.getAuthentication("user", password: "password", completion:  {(success) -> Void in

})
```

Comment: thanks! this works! well, i forgot the dispatch_async thats why I'm not getting anything even though I'm doing the completion handlers

Answer (score 1):

You may pass an escaping closure argument to getAuthentication method.

```
func getAuthentication(username: String, password: String, completion: (JSON) -> ()){
    ...
    // create a request in the same way
    ...
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
            print(swiftyJSON)
            completion(swiftyJSON)
        } else {
            print("There was an error")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And call getAuthentication in LoginViewController like this:

```
getAuthentication(username, password) { (json) -> in
    //Do whatever you want with the json result
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // Do UI updates
    }
}
```

Another way to go is calling getAuthentication in a background thread in your LoginViewController to avoid blocking the main thread (i.e. UI thread).

```
//In LoginViewController   
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
      getAuthentication(username, password)
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         // UI updates
     }
}
```